# Small MySQL database backup interrupts TCP traffic

Tags: asp.net, mysql, tcp, backup

I have a system I'm developing as follows:

-At any one time, three or four clients which are pumping data to the central server over a TCP socket.
-A Windows 7 Pro, 2.4ghz Dual-Core Xeon server with 4gb (soon to be 8gb) of RAM, which houses both an C# ASPX web application that receives the client data, as well as the MySQL database that the data is then put into.
-A mini-PC that stores the database backups, which are done every night. The batch file that I run, which works fine when there's no incoming TCP traffic, is:

> @echo off
>   echo Running dump...
>   net use z: \\BackupComputerName\SharedFolder >c:\debuglog.txt 2>&1
>   cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
>   mysqldump.exe -uroot -pmypassword --result-file="z:\backup.sql" database_name
>   echo Done!

Right now, the database dumps are only about 5 megabytes. Even so, I notice that when the Xeon server carries them out while there's incoming TCP traffic, the client TCP sockets are significantly slowed down, if not disconnected entirely. And the database dump doesn't make it successfully to the backup machine. In fact, it started running in the Windows Task Manager at 8:20pm last night, and as of right now (12:21pm), it's still listed as running! (With no backup file generated yet.) I don't think that it's a coincidence that one of my clients died about a minute after the backup task was triggered last night.

Any ideas for how to reconfigure the backup routine and/or system configuration to make this work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question might be better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Have `mysqldump` create a local file, then use `rsync` with the `--bwlimit` option, or `robocopy` with the `/IPG:n` option to copy over the file to the network share:

```
@echo off
echo Running dump...
net use z: \\BackupComputerName\SharedFolder >c:\debuglog.txt 2>&1
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
mysqldump.exe -uroot -pmypassword --result-file="%temp%\backup.sql" database_name
robocopy "%temp%\backup.sql" z:\ /IPG:100
echo Done!
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick answer. I haven't had a chance to test it out yet, but if it's copying the data over in small chunks, I'm hopeful that'll do the trick. I'll let you know what happens soon.

Comment: So it turns out the problem was actually a thread in my ASPX application that was chewing up a huge amount of CPU. Once I cleaned up that and a few other things, the dump worked fine with my original script. Still, it's likely I'll be using your solution in the future once my database gets larger, so thanks again for posting it.

Comment: Since I answered your question, would you mind upvoting it? Thanks!